# How can I run a server-side blocking loop of computation steps, and allow the client to periodically update the computation parameters?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

**Desired functionality**

I have a toolbox for running a simulation and visualising the activity in the model. I have a React WebSocket client and a FlaskSocketIO server. I require only one socket: one end user and one client connection.

A simulation is just a series of computation steps which are executed in a loop. The number of steps - iterations - is fixed. Let's say a complete simulation has 30 steps.

After completing a step, the server must send the resulting data to the client via the WebSocket. The end user can then observe in "real time" a visualisation of the resulting data, at each step.

At any time during the simulation, the end user must also be able to change the simulation config (the current config will directly impact the computation and output at a given step). Therefore the client must be able to send the user-specified config to the server in real-time, such that each subsequent simulation step - loop iteration - runs its computation using these updated config values.

**Example**

We therefore have something like this:

1. The client establishes WebSocket connection with the server
2. The client sends a "start_simulation" message to the server, with an initial simulation config
3. The server initialises the simulation loop. Each iteration of the loop (each step of the simulation) runs its computation and then pauses for 1s, before moving onto the next iteration (step) and repeating
4. At step 1, the simulation runs its computation using the initial config
5. The client sends an "update_simulation_config" message to the server
6. The server overwrites the simulation's existing config with the new values from the client. Subsequent steps run their computation using the new config, continuing to send the step result to the client for visualisation
7. The end user can now see in real-time how changing the simulation config affects the activity

**Proposed server implementation blueprint**

```
@socketio.on('start_simulation')
def start_simulation(cfg):
    simulator = Simulator(cfg)
    for x in range(config.simulation_steps):
        step_result = simulator.run_step()
        emit('simulation_step_result', step_result)

@socketio.on('update_simulation_config')
def update_simulation_config(cfg):
    simulator.set_config(cfg)
```

**My questions**

1. How can I "share" the same instance of the Simulator class across all the requests received during the lifetime of the single socket?
2. Am I right in thinking that the socket handler in which the simulation loop runs, will block the server, such that it can no longer receive the client message to update the simulation config?
3. If so, I would need to run the simulation in a background thread, but I would then need a way for the main thread, upon receiving the updated config from the client, to update the simulation config in the background thread. Is this possible/recommended?
4. Alternatively, could I pass the "update simulation config" socket handler down to the simulation object itself?